# Virtual Machine with Two NIC's Losing Internet

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-machines, remote-desktop-services, cloud-hosting

Please Forgive my newbieness... I'm just a developer trying to learn a little of the hardware side. I've tried to look this question up but all results produce VMWare which I am not using.

I've created a domain with 1&1.com cloud servers. I have two virtual machines one of them is a Server 2012 R2 Active Directory Domain Controller using DHCP and the second server is a 2012 R2 Server which is running my DNS and RDS services. I am using 1&1's VPN to keep these two within the same network... it works but I have one big problem with internet connection on the RDS Server namely because both servers have TWO network adapters as shown:[image]
[image]

```
Details about network adapter diagnosis: 

Network adapter Ethernet1 driver information:

   Description . . . . . . . . . . : vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter
   Manufacturer  . . . . . . . . . : VMware, Inc.
   Provider  . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware, Inc.
   Version   . . . . . . . . . . . : 1.6.6.0
   Inf File Name . . . . . . . . . : C:\Windows\INF\oem2.inf
   Inf File Date . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, August 20, 2015  3:58:54 AM
   Section Name  . . . . . . . . . : vmxnet3.ndis630.x64.ndi
   Hardware ID . . . . . . . . . . : pci\ven_15ad&dev_07b0
   Instance Status Flags . . . . . : 0x180600a
   Device Manager Status Code  . . : 0
   IfType  . . . . . . . . . . . . : 6
   Physical Media Type . . . . . . : 14
```

I believe the first adapter is my local... I've tried modifying this one with disastrous results... the second one is the VPN which works... but I need to get the internet connection of the first one. Is there a way to combine the two? Or maybe I am thinking of this incorrectly... maybe my configuration is off. I've tried to research and read on this but there doesn't seem to be too much on Domain deployment with 1&1 everything these days is about Azure... and I've only gotten this far by reading up on this but Azure's Network environment is different. Any help or suggestions would be HUGELY appreciated!

Comment: You don't have the same IP on both adapters do you?

Comment: @NickW Thanks for response! Both NIC's are set to "Obtain an IP address automatically" AND "Obtain DNS server address automatically" which I assume is best with DHCP instead of static?

Comment: So, DHCP is fine, VPNs to connect the machines for internal communication.. what does your routing table look like, and what is your actual issue (no internet, intermittent internet?)

Comment: Sorry not familiar with "routing table"? When I hit windows trouble shooter it fixes the internet for a few minutes sometimes... but then it fails again with the results above as in the second screen shot.

Comment: The following link is dealing with wired taking prescience over wifi ... but it might be informational to your current problem http://helpdeskgeek.com/networking/force-windows-7-to-use-wired-connection-over-wireless/

Comment: @CaffeineAddiction Thank you. I tried both suggestions from the article... but unfortunately neither one of them made a difference in my case.

Comment: If I understand your question, you would like to have connection between two your servers and at the same time you want to have connection to your servers from Internet. If I'm right, please share network configuration on both servers. I think there is two network adapters with default gateways, and that cause problems.

Comment: Are the physical adapters on the hosts Broadcom?

Comment: @AlexanderT It appears your suggestion was the solution.  If you post as an answer, I'll vote you up and you should be awarded the bonus points.

Comment: @AlexanderT Yes, for sure... Post it as the answer and I'll award itq

Comment: Good catch @Colyn1337 I did not catch that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you would like to have connection between two your servers and at the same time you want to have connection to your servers from Internet.

Look like you have two NICs with default gateway. In that case server could send traffic to wrong gateway and could be unreacheble. Usually removing default gateway on one NIC(usually it done on local network) could fix such problems.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be the fact that I had two gateways within the domain. Obvious for you experienced Admins, but I post it for any others who may experience this problem who are learning like me.